# Sharepoint subsite 404

Tags: 404

I have one site which also contains one subsite. It works on local machine and is available from machine's IP (192.168.0.37:90), but subsite is not accessible and gives 404.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone (I mean a site owner at least) deleted your subsite and you got an orphan url. But as the above answer it is too little info

Comment: It was exactly the same story with me

Answer (score 1):

Go to [subsiteurl]/_layouts/settings.aspx

If you see this page under your subsite, It might be possible that the home page of subsite is deleted or dont have a published version.

If not, you don't have a working subsite.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but that is too little information to really help you.

- You could at first tell us what version and edition of SharePoint you use.
- Then you could expain all the steps you have already gone though.
- After that you may post what you found in the SharePoint log file (you find it in the log folder of your "hive" - e.g. "Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\logs")

Also information about you DNS, HOSTS file and AAM (Alterlate access mapping in Central Admin) are key to help you.